# how to set environment variable java unix .getenv(NOT_WORKING)

Tags: java, jar, environment-variables, wordnet, jwi

`printenv WNHOME`
`echo $WNHOME`
both give me the correct answer but the java program does not.

I'm trying to execute the example program featured in the [JWI (the MIT Java Wordnet Interface)](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/), the first one featured in the 'User's Manual', as expressed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525372/mit-java-wordnet-interface-getting-wordnet-lexicographer-classes-or-super-sense) question. However, when running the code I keep getting the error `java.net.MalformedURLException`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540090/java-malformedurl-exception-when-constructing-a-url-object) is a discussion which seems to be dealing with a similar issue however I've attempted the solutions therein proposed to no avail.

The code looks like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import edu.mit.jwi.*;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.IIndexWord;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.ILexFile;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.ISenseKey;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.IWord;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.IWordID;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.POS;

public class MITJavaWordNetInterface 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    // construct the URL to the Wordnet dictionary directory
    String wnhome = System.getenv("WNHOME");
    String path = wnhome + File.separator + "dict";
    System.out.println("Path is '" + path + "'"); 
    URL url = new URL ("file", null , path );
    //final URL url = Paths.get(wnhome, "dict").toUri().toURL();

    // construct the dictionary object and open it
    IDictionary dict = new Dictionary ( url ) ;
    dict . open () ;

    // look up first sense of the word "dog "
    IIndexWord idxWord = dict . getIndexWord ("dog", POS . NOUN ) ;
    IWordID wordID = idxWord . getWordIDs () . get (0) ;
    IWord word = dict . getWord ( wordID ) ;
    System . out . println ("Id = " + wordID ) ;
    System . out . println (" Lemma = " + word . getLemma () ) ;
    System . out . println (" Gloss = " + word . getSynset () . getGloss () ) ;      
}       
}
```

There was a prerequisite step of setting the system environment variable `WNHOME` to the location of the root of my Wordnet istallation, which I've duly completed. My `WNHOME` variable is `/usr/local/WordNet-3.0`. What else could be the cause of this error? How can it be resolved?

I tried changing the URL to the following (equally ineffective).

```
final URL url = Paths.get(wnhome, "dict").toUri().toURL();
```

The results of `System.out.println("Path is '" + path + "'");` is:

```
Path is 'null/dict'
```

The full error is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Dictionary directory does not exist: null/dict
    at edu.mit.jwi.data.FileProvider.open(FileProvider.java:306)
    at edu.mit.jwi.DataSourceDictionary.open(DataSourceDictionary.java:92)
    at edu.mit.jwi.CachingDictionary.open(CachingDictionary.java:133)
    at MITJavaWordNetInterface.main(MITJavaWordNetInterface.java:28)
```

Comment: Let's see. You are trying to create a URL with the protocol being " file " (with spaces) - so the URL would look like " file ://path/to/file/goes/here" (also with spaces). Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: That was how the example was formulated, I suppose it's incorrect? how to resolve it?

Comment: Add the full stacktrace please ant show what is the content of `path`

Comment: Presumably you want the protocol to be "file" without spaces. (You do know how URLs work right?). Just remove the spaces...

Comment: `" file "` is not a valid protocol. `"file"` is. You have way too many white spaces everywhere.

Comment: how to add a full stacktrace. I only vaugely know how URLs work I guess. I thought I knew, but it seems I don't. How do they work?

Comment: removed the spaces, still broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have copied-and-pasted this code from somewhere.

The code as you are trying to run it has lots of extraneous spaces.  Either they were inserted by whatever you used to copy-and-paste, or they were added by the compositing software.

Some of the extra spaces are harmless, but there are (at least) 3 places where they are harmful:

```
String wnhome = System.getenv(" WNHOME ");
String path = wnhome + File.separator + " dict ";
URL url = new URL (" file ", null , path ) ;
```

Remove the extraneous spaces in the 3 string literals, and the code is likely to behave (more or less) correctly.

---

Lesson: it is a bad idea to copy code from textbooks ... when you don't understand what the code is doing and/or the programming language it is written in.

---

If that doesn't fix the problem, then print out what the `path` component are:

```
System.out.println("Path is '" + path + "'");
```

and show us the complete stacktrace and the complete exception message.

---

> the result was Path is 'null/dict'

That means that `wnhome` is `null`, which means that either you have not set the environment variable correctly, or the environment variable *name* you are looking up is incorrect.

Comment: I just tried that, I edited the OP to reflect my changes, but still it's disfunctional.

Comment: your solution did not work. one would think in order to proffer explicit lessons a prerequisite might be offering actionable solutions.

Comment: 1) The changes I suggested are NECESSARY whether or not they completely solve your problem.  2)  The lesson would be correct even if the changes I suggested were wrong ... which they aren't.

Comment: Nonetheless, that is the problem.  Perhaps you are executing the code in a different context.  Perhaps you haven't recompiled ...